# How to set up remote desktop connection in Windows 10 (Pro) to connect to a PC remotely?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

I want to connect to another PC from my PC and I am trying to set up `Remote Desktop`. I found a way to access and allow remote connections.

I am using `Windows 10 Pro`.

I followed some tutorials where somebody explains what I need to type in the search box.
The tutorial said:

> open the Windows Start Menu, search for Remote Desktop, select Remote Desktop Connection

The problem is I only found `Access to remote App`, but not `Remote Desktop`.
 How to access `Remote Desktop`?

Answer (score 2):

To set up a **remote desktop connection** in Windows 10, which is used to **connect to a PC remotely,** you need to do two steps:

---

##### I.) Preparation on the remote PC

(which you want to connect to)

This preparation is required just one time. Per default, Windows doesn't allow remote connections, so you need to enable them first and define which users are allowed to connect:

0. Add **"This PC"** to Windows start menu.
1. Right-click and select
   **This PC** => More => Properties
2. On the **"About"** screen, click on the
   **"Advanced system settings"** link (you might need to scroll down) 
   => confirm elevation
3. On the dialog, select
   **Remote tab**
4. On the remote tab, there is a
   **Remote Desktop** section. 
   Select 
   **"Allow remote connections to this computer"** radio button, 
   activate **"Allow connections only from computers ... with Network Level Authentication"**
5. Click <kbd>Select users...</kbd>, then
   add yourself with <kbd>Add</kbd>

In Windows command shell (to get it, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `cmd.exe`), then type

> `Hostname`

To get the name of the remote PC. **Ping** it **from your PC** to make sure it is available on your network. If it can't be resolved, try to ping it using **the remote PCs IP address** (on the remote PC, type `ipconfig -all` to get it) - and as a workaround use the IP address to connect.

**Troubleshooting hints:** If it still doesn't work maybe the listening port 3389 might be  blocked by a firewall. There are two ways to resolve it: 1. Edit the firewall rules to allow that port on the remote PC. 2. You can try to change the listening port, following [this instruction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port).

---

##### II.) On your PC

(which you use to connect to the remote PC)

To connect to the remote PC, open a Windows command shell (to get it, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `cmd.exe` there), and type:

> `mstsc`  
> (and press enter)

The remote desktop dialog opens. Type in the hostname you got from your remote PC and click "connect".

You will be now asked for the username and password (your credentials). Enter them and you will be connected with the remote PC.

---

**Hints:**

- You can save this connection to be used later. For command line options of `mstsc` type

> `mstsc /?`

- In your remote session <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> can be accessed via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- This description works with elevated rights. If you don't have full administrator rights, this is the way to go (because the remote desktop switch in Windows settings might be blocked).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively type <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open RUN dialog, type `mstsc` and click OK was the solution.