# How to optimise a VM for gaming

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, graphics-card, virtualization, gaming

Me and my friend like to play a game called "Red dead redemption 2" but sadly his PC is pretty weak and that's why he doesn't want to play anymore. Yesterday we came up with a solution. My PC is pretty high-end and I thought, that I can maybe "split" my PC into 2 by using a VM software and a remote desktop sharing software like Teamviewer or Chrome remote dekstop. On the way I ran into a lot of problems.

First I used Virtualbox but there were VRAM limitation there which were capped at 256 MB VRAM which is not enough for Red dead redemption 2. Later I looked into using Vmware but sadly found no particular information on VRAM. By the way I also found out that there is a really good Remote Desktop Software named Parsec which is really good supposedly but after I installed it on Virtual Box it said that it needed a more powerful graphics card, because Virtualbox only register an integrated graphics card into the VM.

So my goal was to search a VM Software that both offered VRAM and a good graphics card for the VM (with that I mean the fake graphics card that is displayed in the VM).

After some research I found Windows Hyper-V and this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZtuiLYnb_g where the guy in the video posts a link to 2 scripts that automatically when executed in PowerShell give your VM a good graphics card. I automatically though that it Hyper-V has no VRAM but I'm not sure so that's my first question.

Later I had problems settings up Hyper-V because the network connection didn't work and either my host PC didn't have connection to the internet or my VM. I also tried all sorts of combination with private, internal, external network on Hyper-V. And that is my second question. In the end I gave up and came here.

To summarize all I just want a balanced performance and quality gaming experience for my friend on a VM. The idea is that I download the game twice basically and he logs on to his account and plays from there via remote desktop share.

Here are my PC specs: CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X, GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6800 16GB VRAM, RAM: 32GB, Storage: currently around 200GB, for any information needed to solve my issue please reply here in the forum or message me on discord: Saul Goodman#5628

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have? And for completeness, which one your friend? Please include the edition if there is one (Home, Professional, Ultimate, Enterprise, Education).

Comment: You should mention that it's going over internet more prominently, not just in a half-sentence in the middle of your post.

Comment: Running any game inside a VM, even if you completely remove RDP from it, is going to be as bad or even worse as what your friend's pc can do already. If you then also game on your pc yourself, it will also be ba dfor you. This just won't work unless you have really high-end specced computer, or server for that matter. You would basically need a dedicated graphics card for this to work, so if this is what you want, buy a 2nd graphics card and put in your pc, then use pass through on the VM. The only way it will work.

Comment: Sharing a GPU between VMs [is possible](https://superuser.com/questions/1675735/is-there-a-way-to-share-a-gpu-with-a-guest-vm-in-the-same-way-we-can-share-a-cpu) but only with dedicated datacenter GPUs :-(  With RDS it's not needed anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so before reading your question entirely, I already arrived at some of the steps you listed there heh. Latency is shouting in my mind.

Yes hyper-v will allow VMs to access a graphics card.

The problem I see here is latency firstly.
Your machine keeping up with frame tranmission over a network that is local would possibly be a problem, but you're saying over the internet ??

Second, you can add a virtual NIC to your machine but the IP has to be made visible to your LAN.

To connect to this IP you'll have to create a route to that IP from the internet, so you'll have to do port forwarding for the RDP port to your VM's IP address which you'll have to statically assign.

That's alot going on between the VM, the Graphics card and CPU use before you hit the fact that your connection and machines have to keep up with the frame rate required to play the game.

You might try this locally first to see if it can be done.

This very much seems like its possible in theory, thats one of the reasons VMs have been designed, to share computing resources rather than dedicating an entire machine in a server farm if it isn't necessary.

But in poking around the internet my first thought seems agreed on: there will be a very large amount of frame latency, and rdp will not be able to refresh fast enough to keep up with it.

Consider it this way.

Standard display:  1280x763.   That's 976640 pixels.
Three channel color per RASTERIZED FRAME.  That's 2929920 bytes per FRAME.
60 fps, 175795200 bytes per SECOND. That's a 167 mb per SECOND. Now you of course the rdp server will try to compress this, because that's raw information.  That would require 60 compression operations per second = Latency.

Video transmission in stream form is additive with key frames, different story but thats how people watch movies online and that uses video files that have been preprocessed. Streaming does something similar.

The point is, RDP is not the tool you want to use.

There are ways to render opengl on a remote machine and display them locally, opengl was originally built to contain this ability, but for your specific rather niche requirement, I don't think that will help.

In short because the use-case is limited and would not likely be something this generation of tech user would need (in the old days someone probably thought up this exact scenario and then abandoned it), likely there is no end to end product available for it.

You could just assume your machine is buff enough to handle all of this, but RDP is mostly used for tech concerns and/or developers accessing their work machines from home for example, its not meant for low latency graphics tranmission at a high frame rate.

There might be some other kind of screen sharing software you might implement that could keep up with all this.

You might for a comparison, just play a video on the vm and see if the screen is choppy for illustrative purposes on the connected client.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time trying to find a solution. In the end it is still a dream I guess. But thanks for your effort of clarifying why it is not possible or rather not preferable.

Comment: yeah I apologize for that. this is the kind of geeky solution tech repressed individuals in my generation would have tried because our comps sucked and bandwidth sucked.   keep searching around though. you may find something.

Answer (score 1):

Get a laptop and meet together at the same place. Or carry the PC over ;-)

Then use [Remote Desktop Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) (RDS)(formerly Terminal Services) over local network. They provide remote connections to Windows installations over which you can run applications on a remote machine! Which would be your powerful computer and are ofter powerful servers in organizations. But normally inside the same building and for Office applications. This is why multiple sessions are enabled by default in server versions of Windows.

For a single session from your friend's PC to yours with you being logged out see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1240499/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-10-pro-to-connect-to-a-pc-r/1691877#1691877).

To enable multiple sessions on a Windows client version use the glorious [rdpwrap](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1548272/difficulty-installing-rdpwrap-on-windows-10-to-get-multiple-remote-desktop-conn/1548312#1548312) for a guide. There even is a [Telegram group](https://t.me/rdpwrap) which can help.

Once set up, your friend can run the [RDP client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) (mstsc) on his machine, log into your computer and start a game there – while sitting at his computer and you on yours also playing the game! All without the overhead of emulating another virtual one.

If you've succeeded locally and not already had enough fun, you could still try to connect via internet. But be aware this bears security risks and probably won't perform well as explained in the previous answer.